# Typescript Generic Array Type and Push Item

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to create a generic function which handles varies arrays of various types (that only share a few properties in common) and perform simple operations such as delete or add an item. How should the typing's look for such a function?

```js
interface A {
    value: number;
    aasdsad?: number;
    abc: string;
}

interface B {
    value: number;
    asdsad1?: string;
}

export class Main {

    public getOneOfTheArrays(): A[] | B[] {
        return []; // return A[] or B[] depending on certain conditions
    }

    public getValue(index: number) {
        const arr: A[] | B[] = this.getOneOfTheArrays();
        const a = this.copy(arr[index]);
        a.value = 1234;
        arr.push(a); // <- typing's error here
    }

    public copy(obj: A | B): A | B {
        return Object.assign({}, obj);
    }

}
```

[DEMO1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20aasdsad%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20abc%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20asdsad1%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20Main%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getOneOfTheArrays()%3A%20A%5B%5D%20%7C%20B%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%5B%5D%3B%20%2F%2F%20return%20A%5B%5D%20or%20B%5B%5D%20depending%20on%20certain%20conditions%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getValue(index%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20arr%3A%20A%5B%5D%20%7C%20B%5B%5D%20%3D%20this.getOneOfTheArrays()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20a%20%3D%20this.copy(arr%5Bindex%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a.value%20%3D%201234%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20arr.push(a)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%3C-%20typing's%20error%20here%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20copy(obj%3A%20A%20%7C%20B)%3A%20A%20%7C%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20obj)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D) [DEMO2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20type%20Get%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20A%20%3F%20A%5B%5D%20%3A%20B%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20Main%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20bob%3CT%3E()%3A%20Get%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%5B%5D%20as%20Get%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getValue%3CT%20extends%20A%20%7C%20B%3E(index%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20arr%3A%20Get%3CT%3E%20%3D%20this.bob()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(arr)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20a%20%3D%20this.copy(arr%5Bindex%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a.value%20%3D%201234%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20arr.push(a)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20copy(obj%3A%20A%20%7C%20B)%3A%20A%20%7C%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20obj)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D)

**Error:** `arr.push(a)` -> Argument of type 'A | B' is not assignable to parameter of type 'A & B'.
  Type 'B' is not assignable to type 'A & B'.
    Property 'abc' is missing in type 'B' but required in type 'A'.

**Solution so far:** `(arr as typeof a[]).push(a);`

Answer (score 3):

You can not push `A | B` to `A[] | B[]` only when `a` is typeof `B` and `arr` typeof `A[]` because type `B` is missing `abc` attribute.

You ar able to push it when:

```js
arr.push(a as A);
(arr as B[]).push(a as B);
(arr as B[]).push(a as A);
```

Sou you have to check i some way that a is B and arr is A[], and it that case apply some different logic.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20aasdsad%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20abc%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20asdsad1%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20Main%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getOneOfTheArrays()%3A%20A%5B%5D%20%7C%20B%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%5B%5D%3B%20%2F%2F%20return%20A%5B%5D%20or%20B%5B%5D%20depending%20on%20certain%20conditions%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getValue(index%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20arr%3A%20A%5B%5D%20%7C%20B%5B%5D%20%3D%20this.getOneOfTheArrays()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20a%20%3D%20this.copy(arr%5Bindex%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a.value%20%3D%201234%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20arr.push(a%20as%20A)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(arr%20as%20B%5B%5D).push(a%20as%20B)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(arr%20as%20B%5B%5D).push(a%20as%20A)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20copy(obj%3A%20A%20%7C%20B)%3A%20A%20%7C%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20obj)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: The closest we got so far: `(arr as typeof a[]).push(a);`

Comment: You will turn off compilation error, but what about case when you're trying to add `B` to `A[]`. You will have array of `A` where one of element has no attribute `abc`. So `arr[42].abc` will be `undefined` when TS will tell you thats string

Comment: That's true. But technically it can only be one type at a given time. I assume what I'm trying to achieve isn't possible?

Comment: As I understand you: its not possible only in case `Array<A>.push(B)` other 3 cases are fine.

Comment: What about with the use of generics and advanced types such as `declare type OneOf<T> = T extends A ? A : B` so it's clear to the developer that the function can only be called with one specific type at a time and that `arr` cannot be `(A|B)[]` at a given moment in time.

Comment: There is another way to to that, method `getOneOfTheArrays` can return proper type based on input attributes. `type Get<T extends boolean> = T extends true ? number[] : string[];` and run it by `let fn = <T extends boolean>(arg: T): Get<T> => [] as Get<T>;` then `fn(false); ` will be `string[]` and `fn(true)` will be `number`

Comment: Please see DEMO2 above

Comment: I't the same logic as in demo1, `blob` method must return exact array type. Based on e.g. arguments or attributes values, so variable `a` can not be union type

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188212/discussion-between-stevanicus-and-przemyslaw-pietrzak).